# How to target accordion li when hovering and targeting the first child?

Tags: html, css

I want to target strictly the menu when hovering. The Menu would change color and size but without affecting the `li` menu. How would I do that?

Note that this is suppose to be an accordion menu. The nav (sub) expands when hovering over Menu. I have spent a great deal of time but I cannot target the Menu without messing up the sub.

```
<nav id="menu_box">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

here is the css:

https://jsfiddle.net/kgrxqL0k/1/

Comment: Please show the CSS you've tried. As the submenu is a child element, it will necessarily affect its parent list item, unless you position the former absolutely and outside the list item.

Comment: this is where JQuery is great, import the JQuery library and then use the selector notation to target the element you want to change and use the onHover() method call. https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Add your css code. You can try to add a css class in the li children of ul.menu

Comment: Where? Edit in your main post

Comment: Something like [this minimal example](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/kgrxqL0k/)?

Comment: thanks, Ive added the css to my main post

Comment: This is my current css I am working on. When hovering over menu, I just want the menu to change size and color, but it doesnt seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
.menu > li li a:hover {
    color: pink;
}
```

---

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 220px;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > ul {
  display: block;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #d8f3f0;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 26px;
  top: 19px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 2px;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: 23px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub.open > a:after,
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub.open > a:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 14px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#menu ul li:hover a {
  color: pink;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  top: 16px;
  right: 26px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  top: 20px;
}
.menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 350px;
}
.menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu li a {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #ccc;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: background;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.menu > li:first-child a {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.menu >li a:hover a:first-child {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #547b16;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  ] -webkit-transition-property: background;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.menu li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu li li a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 0;
  color: #1F3D39;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.menu > li:hover li a {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.menu > li:hover li a:hover {
  -webkit-transition-property: background;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.menu > li li a:hover {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu_box">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">sub</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you isherwood, but i was looking for an accordion style and when hovered, the menu changes size and color. Is there possibly another way?